# how to get access to a distant oracle server

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I have never worked on an oracle database, however, now I need to use php (executed on a different server) to log into the oracle database, but it seems that there is some missing data.

what I have:

- **Ip address** of the server and the **port** 1521 (ping OK from the server running my php)
- **data base's name**
- **user** with all privileges
- the server is perfectly working (another application that is totally relying on the oracle server is perfectly working)

what I don't have:

- **Service Name**
- The used **Oracle version** (more likely 11g but not sure)
- any kind of **access** to the **server's system**

I tried some guessed service names but I get:

> ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

I tried some other alternatives such using SID but still the same error with SID this time instead of service:

> ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

All the other solutions I found require an access to the server to run some scripts or commands, but this is impossible for my case.

The code I use :

```
$user = 'myUser';
$password = 'myPassword';
$database = 'MY_DB'; 
$conn=oci_connect($user,$password,
'(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.l.l00)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = someName)
    )
  )');

if ($conn) {
   echo "connected";
}
else
{
    echo "not connected";
}
```

with the error message followed by "not connected" as a result on my browser.
So, is it possible to somehow log into the database? or is it impossible?

Comment: This is probably a question for the DBA's or whoever is responsible for the database.

Comment: Thanks  @NigelRen for your comment, the issue is that the DBA is unfortunately uncontactable. but I am still hoping to find some tricks.

Comment: There are no "tricks".  Your error clearly indicates you are reaching the listener, but the listener doesn't know of the database (sid or service name) you are requesting.  You need to know what the listener _does_ know about.  And for that you will need to contact the DBA.

Comment: When you say you tried the SID, did you replace the `SERVICE_NAME` keyword with `SID` in connect string: `(SID = someName)`?  (But if you do use service name, then make life easier and simplify the whole string to the Easy Connect form `"192.168.l.l00/someName"`).  You do need some DB access to be able to interrogate it and find what connection string to use.

Comment: thank you @EdStevens for your reply, I am running a script that tries to find the service name by generating all possible cases and putting oci_connect in a while(!$conn) loop, hoping for some thing.

Comment: Exactly @ChristopherJones, I tried SID instead of service_name. I still do not have any access to the database, thank for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the DBA gave me the missing information

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).